# Nopcommerce - how to set up Admin in new project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nopcommerce

As the title suggests, we are building a new application, and would like to set up our administration area as a new project as nopcommerce does.

We are trying this on a sample project at the moment,  and what we have so far is :-

1. Created a new MVC Application called App1
2. Right clicked the solution >  add new project - selected MVC application and changed the location to a new Admin folder under the App1 Application. This all now looks the same as nopCommerce.
3. Right clicked the Admin project, under build,  changed the ouput to ..\bin\

As far as i can see,  this seem to be it?

I rebuild the solution, and check the bin directory in application, and the dll's from the admin site are all there.

I release the main site (App1) and check. There is no Admin folder created, and no admin dll in the bin directory..

What other steps are we missing?

UPDATE : Ive added a new project into the nopcommerce solution, using the exact same steps 2 and 3, and this works with no issues.  So it seems that there is something within either the webproject or against the solution in nopcommerce that is making this work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check clearassamly project in nopcommerce which run after every build to clean up plugins dll